# how to add class object and get that value in view page in spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have done one small spring program. i want to print the value of another class properties. this is my program

```
enter 
@Controller
public class springtest2 
{
    @RequestMapping(value="/spring")
    public ModelAndView data(@RequestParam("name") String name) 
    {
         ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("view");
         model.addObject("msg",name);
         model.addObject("lastname", "abbass");

         Demo dd=new Demo();
         dd.setName("faisal");
         dd.setTown("mayiladuthurail");
         model.addObject("object", dd);  // it shows error. i don't know why

         return model;
     }
 }
```

Demo class coding

```
code her
package com.test2.springtest2;

public class Demo 
{
    private String name;
    private String town;

    void setName(String name)
    {
      this.name=name;
    }
    void setTown(String town)
    {
      this.town=town;
    }

    String getName()
    {
      return name;
    }

    String getTown()
    {
       return town;
    }
 }
```

view .jsp coding

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
   <html>
   <head> 
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title> 
     </head> 

     <body> 
     Name:<p>${msg}</p>
     Last name:<p>${lastname}</p>

     object name:<p>${object.name}</p> object town:<p>${object.town}</p>  
     </body> 
     </html>
```

when i run my app this is my error message

```
    HTTP ERROR 500

    Problem accessing /spring. Reason:

    Could not find property name in class com.test2.springtest2.Demo
    Caused by:

    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find property name in class      
    com.test2.springtest2.Demo
```

please help me friends...

Answer (score 0):

Getters getName() and getTown() must be public in the Demo  file to let spring access them. Or you can make the fields public.

Comment: thank you so much i got it... ok i want to download spring 4.1.4 jar file. can you suggest any site?

Comment: It's better to use build tool e.g. maven. spring is not just one file but have a lot of dependencies for different parts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your functions public

```
 public class Demo 
    {
        private String name;
        private String town;

        public void setName(String name)
        {
          this.name=name;
        }
        public void setTown(String town)
        {
          this.town=town;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
          return name;
        }

        public String getTown()
        {
           return town;
        }
     }
```